# Protect Passwords in wp_users with stronger protection than MD5

Tags: password, hacks

I prefer a better and stronger kind of passwords for my wp sites. After watching below MD5 tube and reading hash plugins, I can not find a good solution for WP.

> Search [hash plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=Hash+Password)!
>
> Why not to use  [MD5 tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U-RbOKanYs)!

In phpmyadmin I only get MD5 and SHA1 what is to easy to hack as you can see in the tube.

But what is really a good protection for all passwords on WP sites? I  can not find it. Do I have to add an extra code-string to all passwords like:
 **@9I_^2u@wB72&_Äbõ**. This will make it very difficult to hack I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password hashing/checking system in WP is *pluggable*, which essentially means that it is designed to be replaceable with custom implementation. This isn't commonly done due to relying on defaults and compatibility. WP tries hard for backwards compat (such as with earliest single MD5 implementation) and portability (hashes from one WP install would work on another).

There are off–the–shelf solutions around that change hashing to a newer and more secure algorithms. At this time this is mostly considered [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) in PHP, which is designed to be future–proof. Algorithm used and salts are embedded in resulting hash, so you can keep moving to stronger algorithms in future, while being able to transparently verify older hashes.

From quick search [roots/wp-password-bcrypt](https://github.com/roots/wp-password-bcrypt) is one of such implementations.

Comment: Yes, @Rarst correct, I messed up the salt for the cookies and the salting  functions inside `HashPassword`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is called the salting but don't confuse it with the:
https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ 
that has the another purpose in WordPress, as I did.

```
---------------------------------------------------
text       | newpass
---------------------------------------------------
md5        | e6053eb8d35e02ae40beeeacef203c1a
---------------------------------------------------
salted md5 | $P$BECVJLnxOXJ3ywcDz0FY0bgUcDFP02/
---------------------------------------------------
```

Your guess was right, if the password would be saved inside the database as md5 you would be able to crack it probably easy.

However, WordPress saves salted md5 passwords inside the database.

This function

```
File: wp-includes/class-phpass.php
225:    function HashPassword($password)
226:    {
227:        if ( strlen( $password ) > 4096 ) {
228:            return '*';
229:        }
230: 
231:        $random = '';
232: 
233:        if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
234:            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(16);
235:            $hash =
236:                crypt($password, $this->gensalt_blowfish($random));
237:            if (strlen($hash) == 60)
238:                return $hash;
239:        }
240: 
241:        if (CRYPT_EXT_DES == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
242:            if (strlen($random) < 3)
243:                $random = $this->get_random_bytes(3);
244:            $hash =
245:                crypt($password, $this->gensalt_extended($random));
246:            if (strlen($hash) == 20)
247:                return $hash;
248:        }
249: 
250:        if (strlen($random) < 6)
251:            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(6);
252:        $hash =
253:            $this->crypt_private($password,
254:            $this->gensalt_private($random));
255:        if (strlen($hash) == 34)
256:            return $hash;
257: 
258:        # Returning '*' on error is safe here, but would _not_ be safe
259:        # in a crypt(3)-like function used _both_ for generating new
260:        # hashes and for validating passwords against existing hashes.
261:        return '*';
262:    }
```

has different salting functions inside.

If you use `wp-cli` to generate the password multiple times, you will notice the different passwords will be generated in each attempt:

```
wp user update 1 --user_pass=newpass
```

This way, if someone get your database it cannot guess your password.

There is some edge case for backward compatilility where you can set md5 non salted passwords in your database and it will work. However, WordPress should be smart to salt that password on the very first login attempt.

In some previous WordPress editions, I can confirm I could set the WordPress password as a plain text and on the very next login attempt the password would be salted. This is not possible any more.

---

Also you may check [wp_generate_password](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_password) and [wp_hash_password](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) for more details.

Comment: So this means no hacks on passwords and so on after adding this in wp-config.php?

Comment: The explanation is little longer I will try to update the post in next 20 min.

Comment: WP is not using those salts in password hashing. If that was true changing salt would invalidate every password of every user.

Comment: I try to add a complex string to every password saved in wp-users with md5 by default. So passwords are saved and controlled by this. If someone of you has a solution then please inform me/us. Now everyone can hack md5 saved passwords within seconds.

Comment: If I'm reading [Security Keys](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Security_Keys) correctly, the salting is for "sessions" and cookies.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, Rarst was correct I incorrectly set the link to the `https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/`, but there is other kind of salt that in the hashing function `HashPassword`.

Comment: @Hermants, I used the wrong link - this is not the correct salt, please accept the Rarst answer as more accurate.